# Android: Confusion in understanding the runtime permissions

Tags: android, android-runtime

I am implementing runtime permissions in my app. I have few questions though to understand them clearly.

**Situation:**

- My *application B* is a child app of *application A*
- That being said my application resides inside *application A* as part of it and, whenever needed I can launch it.

**Question:**

1. If a user has already granted all the necessary runtime permissions to *application A* (the parent app), then can the child app i.e. *application B* carry the same permission grant or it has to ask them again?
2. Do I need to ask the permissions again if I install a newer version of an app on top of the old? Let's say version 2 to 3.

Comment: What does "My application(B) is a child app of application (A)" mean? What does "my application resides in side application A as part of it and whenever needed I can launch it" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare there is a button inside parent app call 'Axis' if you click that it will open up a child app named 'Axis' with few data to move forward with the job

Comment: So app(B) is really just a whole other app that gets some kinda intent/data from app(A)?

Comment: @TWL yes you got it right.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes. If app-A and app-B are two separate apps, they each need their own set of permissions and permission requests.

And no, if a permission was previously allowed, then an installation of a newer version does not reset that permission's state.

However, if you want app-B to retain the same permission states as app-A, you should look into something called [android:sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid). If app-A has the same *sharedUserId* as app-B, then app-B will have the same permission states as app-A, and vice versa.

I couldn't find any posts talking sufficiently about the shared permission states between apps with the same, but you can check out some of these posts for extra notes:

- [Two app with shared UserID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269956/two-app-with-shared-userid)
- [What is sharedUserId in Android, and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783765/what-is-shareduserid-in-android-and-how-is-it-used)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492023/6668797
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8507761/6668797

I did a quick test myself and can confirm that two apps with the same sharedUserId do share permission states, so go try it yourself. Just setup a sample project/app that checks and requests a permission, clone it, give them the same `sharedUserId`, install both of them, allow the permission on one, and you'll see it's already in the allowed-state on the other.

Comment: thanks. This is a useful one. So, what can be the disadvantages of this approch?

Comment: and what does it mean by 'both the app have to sign same certificate'?

Comment: I can't comment about disadvantages with certainty, but your 2nd question means both the apps must be signed by the same key.

Comment: What can be possible disadvantages you can think?

Comment: This question is worthy of its own post, please, thanks!